# Migration 2010 to 2013 (different languages)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, migration

I want to migrate SP 2010 (1049) to SP 2013 (1033) + language pack (1049), can there be problems?

Comment: You cannot change an existing site, site collection, or web page from one language to another by applying different language-specific site templates. After you use a language-specific site template for a site or a site collection, the site or site collection always displays content in the language of the original site template.

Comment: @user66019, thanks, after the migration, I will write later))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short answer: **No**

You have already prepared your SharePoint 2013 farm with the **Russian Language Pack (1049)** so it should be migrated without any issue related to language.

Comment: Take your time :)